# Rendering text in WPF so that it perfectly fits in a given rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I need to display words on a WPF Canvas in such a way that they perfectly fit in pre-defined boxes.

One box typically contains a single line of text, from one letter to a few words.

The text inside a box must be as large as possible, i.e: touching all borders of the box (except maybe where it would cause too much text distortion due to abnormal box witdh/height ratio).

I could not find a good way to calculate the appropriate font height, scaling and offset, based on the text content.

A first solution where the original text width/height ratio can't be changed would already be very nice !

I'd like to use TextBlock elements, but anything else that works should be ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the answer by Robery Levy said, you can use a `Viewbox` to achieve this. The text itself won't stretch however so you'll still have some "margin" on zero or more sides depending on your text (as you noticed). To work around this you can create a custom control which builds a `Geometry` from a `FormattedText` and then draw this with `DrawGeometry` in OnRender. You'll notice how the quality of the text improves with a larger `FontSize`. A very small text (e.g. `FontSize="10"`) won't look very sharp in a large `Viewbox` so you'll have to experiment a bit

[image]

**Some sample Xaml**

```
<Canvas Background="Black">
    <Viewbox Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"
             Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="50">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <local:StretchText Text="Text" Foreground="Green" FontSize="100"/>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Canvas.Left="230" Canvas.Top="10"
             Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="50">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <local:StretchText Text="B" Foreground="Green" FontSize="500"/>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</Canvas>
```

**StretchText.cs**

```
public class StretchText : Control
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
            Text,
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretches.Normal),
            FontSize,
            Foreground);

        Geometry textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));
        this.MinWidth = textGeometry.Bounds.Width;
        this.MinHeight = textGeometry.Bounds.Height;

        TranslateTransform translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        translateTransform.X = -textGeometry.Bounds.Left;
        translateTransform.Y = -textGeometry.Bounds.Top;
        drawingContext.PushTransform(translateTransform);
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Foreground, new Pen(Foreground, 1.0), textGeometry);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(StretchText),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tested it and it works pretty well. In the meantime I found an alternative solution: measuring the text elements via a temporary FormattedText object (thanks to properties "Width", "Extent" and "OverhangAfter"), then apply a Scale+TranslateTransform to each element accordingly. However, it has two disadvantages: actual text blocks objects become too big (messing tooltips), and the rendering is not as fast as I would like.

Comment: @Jem: No problem :) How was the rendering time between our solutions? Was it "to slow" in both cases? I tried with 10 or so `StretchText` simultaneously in a `Grid` and then resized the `Window` quickly. I seemed to work pretty nicely but `DrawGeometry` is known for being pretty slow

Comment: the number of words to display is about one or two thousand, but resizing the page is smooth enough with your solution. I'd say it's about 3 times faster than mine, and it's stable (no "lags"). However, the text quality is not as sharp for small text (probably because it's not "text" anymore, but "geometry"), but it's good enough. Ideally I'd like even better performance and the best possible text quality, but your solution is the best compromise for now.

Comment: @Jem: Ok great :) For the text quality, if you haven't tried it, try to increase the font size for sharper text.

Answer (score 4):

Put the TextBlock inside a Viewbox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx

Comment: Thank, just tried. Interesting but it does not do exactly what I need: it's not aware of the text content as-is. For example I still have margins under the text unless a letter crosses the baseline (such as 'g', 'p', 'y' 'q'). I really need the input box to be the text "bouding box".

Answer (score 0):

You could check out Charles Petzold's article  "[Render Text on a Path with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx)". Unfortunately I can't refresh my knowledges about subject at present moment due to something goes wrong with MSDN site, but he described how to scale text within path.